# don't display content outside of border wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't want to display content that is outside the border in my wpf application. Here is an image to illustrate better my point:

[image]

in that picture the blue box is the border and note that its child is a listview. I don't want to display the entire listview. I just want to display whatever is inside the blue border.

What control do I have to use in order to achive that? I am looking for some sort of a mask... Is creating a custom user control my only option?

Comment: not really clear what you want to achieve, sorry. Do you want that `ListView` is **always** inside `border`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True">
    <ListView .../>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just set [`ClipToBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) to `true` on the border and it should be cut off.